# SED: Removing last character before EOL and adding some text using the old one

Tags: regex, unix, text, sed

I have the following line:

```
env JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=/the_path/:/the_path/:/the_path/:/the_path:"$LIBRARY_PATH" -Xms2g -Xmx4g -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -Dsun.net.client.defaultConnectTimeout=60000 -Dsun.net.client.defaultReadTimeout=60000 -Dspring.profiles.active=release"
```

I want to add new variable before the last quotation mark (something like a new_fancy_variable=yes). So this line should be look like that:

```
env JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=/the_path/:/the_path/:/the_path/:/the_path:"$LIBRARY_PATH" -Xms2g -Xmx4g -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -Dsun.net.client.defaultConnectTimeout=60000 -Dsun.net.client.defaultReadTimeout=60000 -Dspring.profiles.active=release new_fancy_variable=yes"
```

The question is how can I do that? At present I have a command:

```
sed 's/^env JAVA_OPTS=\".*$/& new_fancy_variable=yes\"/' myfile.conf
```

...but I don't know how I can remove the last question mark before new variable.

Answer (score 1):

`sed '/^env JAVA_OPTS=/s/"$/ new_var=yes"/' ...`

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the `env`. You can postfix values to a var with `myvar+="additopnal=value".
Your original`JAVA_OPTS` can be constructed like

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=/the_path/:/the_path/:/the_path/:/the_path:$LIBRARY_PATH"
# Add mem setings
JAVA_OPTS+=" Xms2g -Xmx4g -XX:MaxPermSize=256M"
# add Timeouts
JAVA_OPTS+=" -Dsun.net.client.defaultConnectTimeout=60000 -Dsun.net.client.defaultReadTimeout=60000"
# Add profile
JAVA_OPTS+=" -Dspring.profiles.active=release"
```

Do not forget to add a space between the words.
Now adding something fancy is easy:

```
JAVA_OPTS+=" new_fancy_variable=yes"
```

When you want to add it to a file, you can try

```
echo '# Fancy support
JAVA_OPTS+=" new_fancy_variable=yes"' >> myfile.conf
```

You only need to check that adding this on the last line is correct (no flow control or sections in your config)